# 気が合う人 is correct but why can't I say 気が合える人？ Why is using the potential form wrong?

Tags: usage, idioms, potential-form

One day a friend of mine told me my usage of 合える人 is grammatically incorrect but when I check on the internet, I see we can use the potential form with 合う.

I want to say that I can potentially get along with a person.

Why is it wrong? Which rule am I breaking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(According to web searches,) there is a distinction called [意志動詞 and 無意志動詞](http://www7a.biglobe.ne.jp/nifongo/1h93fy/ishi.html). The former denotes the verbs that express voluntary actions.

The rule is that there is no potential form for 無意志動詞, which 合う in 気が合う belongs to.

For comparison, 分かり合う is a voluntary action, so 分かり合える is fine.

(Another confusing element may be the English "get along", which may well be understood as a voluntary action.)

---

Another example may be instructive (partially from the link above).

- 医者になる　→　医者になれる
- 春になる　→　<strike>春になれる</strike>

To be a doctor is something one does at her own will, but the coming of spring is not. Hence the difference.

Comment: So, to express 'could get along with', would one say "気が合う機能性がある" or something of the sort?

Comment: How about 気が合いそう

Comment: Thank you! I'm always confused about the voluntary action verbs... In French or English we use the potential form for non-voluntary action verbs too, as a possibility. I've never seen a book explaining which form to use in this case.

@rjh 's answer is what I'd use next but that requires an effort to change the way we think.

Comment: @Robin 気が合いそう may be the most idiomatic while 気が合う可能性がある/気が合うかもしれない are possible.

Comment: @sundowner Thanks! I thought 気が合いそう might be more natural but was directly translating "^^

Comment: @Alexis It may be kind of similar that "the door won't open" is more common (I believe) than "the door can't open". (開く is another verb without potential form)